# Android - UnsatisfiedLinkError: setAndroidSdkVersion

Tags: android

I have modified the linphone-android source codes for my own app. It works fine on android version 2.3.3 to 2.3.6, but when I tried running it on android 4.0.3 (Galaxy S II), it returns me this error: "UnsatisfiedLinkError: setAndroidSdkVersion", which I do not have any idea what is it about.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Here is what I have gotten from the logcat.

[image]